# ERB String interpolation generating incorrect HTML syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these lines in a view:

```
<%
  if current_user.is_fav?(a)
    cls = "product fav"
  else
    cls = "product"
  end
%>
```

and later

```
<div class=<%= cls %> >
```

This produces:

```
<div class="product" fav>
```

EDIT: as the answer says, it did NOT produce this, it was the browser "inspect" that showed it to me.

I can work my around it, but why doesn't the above code work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This produces:
>
> ```
> <div class="product" fav>
> ```

No, it doesn't. It produces `<div class=product fav>`. What you **see** (via something like "inspect element", correct?) is browser trying to interpret your broken markup as close to html spec as it can.

As noted in other answers, what you should do instead is something like this:

```
<div class="<%= cls %>">
```

Comment: correct! I was using inspect element, had no idea that it worked the way it did. Also, the browser only displays using the first class which threw me off guard.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class=<%= cls %> >
```

should probably be

```
<div class="<%= cls %>">
```

You're substituting a string into an erb placeholder, but the underlying template does not indicate that the placeholder itself is a string.  <strike>ERB is likely making a best effort attempt to do a correction but it's oviously not able to cope.</strike> Edit: Sergio pointed out this is likely the browser doing this, not ERB.